# Optional<String> map function returns null

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring, option-type, optional-parameters

Can someone help me with the below piece of code? I would like an equivalent using `Optional` functions.

```
public String getMyRequiredValue(Optional<String> value) {
    if(value.isPresent()) {
        Optional<String> optionVal = getAnotherValue(value.get());
        if(optionVal.isPresent()) {
            return optionVal.get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return "Random";
    }
}

public Optional<String> getAnotherValue(String value) { ... }
```

Just a note I tried this, but it does not work

```
return value.map(lang -> getAnotherValue(lang).orElse(null)).orElse("Random");
```

The thing that is not working is - when the value is present and `getAnotherValue` returns `Optional.empty()` I want the original function to return `null`. It is returning `"Random"` right now.

My assumption is since the `map` method returns `null` it gets replaced by `"Random"`.

Note that the original code was written by someone else. Since, it has a lot of dependencies, I cannot change the input/output parameters. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution originally suggested by [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) in the comments:

```
public String getMyRequiredValue(Optional<String> value) {
    return value.isPresent() ? getAnotherValue(value.get()).orElse(null) : "Random";
}
```

The solution I came up with first. It breaks the rule that suggests we always need to check `isPresent()` before calling `get()` and introduces exception handling. So it's better to stick to the first idea.

```
public String getMyRequiredValue2(Optional<String> value) {
    try {
        return getAnotherValue(value.get()).orElse(null);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "Random";
    }
}
```

I've seen you were trying to utilise `map` and `flatMap`. If they result in an `Optional.empty()`, it's unclear where `null` came from: it could be either `value` or `getAnotherValue(value.get())`.

We could track that by saving the value coming from `value.get()` into a `Holder<String>`:

```
public String getMyRequiredValue3(Optional<String> value) {
    final Holder<String> holder = new Holder<>();
    return value.flatMap(i -> getAnotherValue(holder.value = i))
                .orElse(holder.value == null ? "Random" : null);
}
```

Again, the first approach still beats this.

---

EDIT: As pointed out by [@Holder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger), we don't need a `Holder` from the preceding example. Instead we can check `value.isPresent()`:

```
public String getMyRequiredValue4(Optional<String> value) {
    return value.flatMap(this::getAnotherValue) 
                .orElse(value.isPresent() ? null : "Random");
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is an anti-pattern. I think you shouldn't even mention that option in yor answer, or at least make it much more clear that it is not a good idea.

Comment: You don’t need that `Holder` object, when you already have the `Optional<String> value` doing exactly that, i.e. containing the same value or being empty. So you can simply use `return value.flatMap(i -> getAnotherValue(holder.value = i)) .orElse(value.isPresent()? null: "Random");`

Comment: Of course, also without the `holder.value = ` part; leftover from copy&paste…